# Call php function with onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to delete project from database.Before deleting I want to confirm it whether user want to delete or not.If user click on okay it has to call delete function.But in the code when user click  the function is get called not only user click on okay but also click on concel.For other alter statement it is working fine.For calling php function only it gives problem.

How can I solve this?

code is,

```
<a href="http://localhost/Performance/project/ShowAllProjects.php?project_id='.$row['project_id'].'"><img src="http://localhost/performance/css/delete.png" title="delete"  alt="running test" style="width:15px;height:15px;border:0;margin-left:1cm" Onclick="deleteProject();"/></a>

<script>
    function deleteProject() {      
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");
        if (r == true) {
            //alert("You pressed OK!");
            alert("<?php confirmDelete(); ?>"); 
        } else {
            alert("You pressed Cancel!");              
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
    function confirmDelete(){
        $sql="DELETE FROM project_table WHERE project_id='".$_GET['project_id']."' AND member_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."';";
        if(mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'], $sql)) {
            echo "Your test deleted successfully";  
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['db']);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: alert() is used for display message, not for calling a function.

Comment: you can try with `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: you should use form post or restful API(ajax) to achieve your goal.

Comment: try <a href="http://localhost/Performance/project/ShowAllProjects.php?project_id=<?php echo $row['project_id'];?>"><img src="http://localhost/performance/css/delete.png" title="delete"  alt="running test" style="width:15px;height:15px;border:0;margin-left:1cm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"/></a>

Comment: Also sanitise user inputs to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Please use prepared statements in your SQL or little kittens will die()

Comment: it is a link you have to prevent the default event of anchor tag which is refreshing the page. Please change deleteProject(event){event.preventDefault();}. I am sure it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow this code to achieve using jQuery ajax call.
This is the HTML code with jQuery included and I've used test.php file in the same directory. Just write your PHP function in test.php file. Finally the response will be displayed in the given div after the user pressed confirm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery ajax</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFun()">Click me</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>
        function myFun(){
            var r= confirm("Press a button!");
        if (r==true)
          {
            $.ajax({url: "test.php", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
            }});  
          }
        else
          {
            alert("You pressed Cancel!");              

          }
        }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to remove your PHP from your view if possible.  If you move you PHP functions into a separate PHP file and call them with AJAX it will allow you to reuse the code on different pages if required.

This is not tested completely but would be a cleaner solution I would say.

Add an id to you delete image:

```
<img id="delete" src="" title="delete"  alt="running test" style="width:15px;height:15px;border:0;margin-left:1cm" onclick="deleteProject()"/>
```

Change your javascript to use AJAX to call the PHP script:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#delete', function(){
    var r= confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r==true)
      {
        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo LOCATION_OF_PHP_SCRIPT; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: DATA_IF_NEEDED
        }).success( resp )
        {
            if( resp == TRUE )
          {
            alert( "Deleted" );
          }

        }
      }
    else
      {
        alert("You pressed Cancel!");              

      }
})
```

You will need to adjust some of the parameters to suit your application but should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

on clicking the div the function read will execute and give hi

```
<?php
function read($id){
   echo $id;
  }
?>


<div onclick="<?php read("hi"); ?>" class="item">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `php` code from `JavaScript`. `JavaScript` is client-side and `php` is server-side.

You have to create a script `deleteThings.php` that delete what you want and call it from client's `JavaScript` using asynchronous `Ajax` request.

For asynchronous `Ajax` request you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), vanilla `JavaScript`, or others libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax for calling PHP function from JAVASCRIPT function.

Check the below code.

$.ajax({

```
type: "POST",

url: 'your_functions.php',

dataType: 'json',

data: {functionname: 'delete'},

success: function (obj, textstatus) {
       }
```

})

your_functions.php